# Load a file from a remote machine in a local ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm running IPython notebook on my local machine and I would like to load/save a file which resides on a remote machine via `%load / %%writefile`. Did anyone tried? Or is it possible? The remote machine is reachable via `ssh`.

Comment: I believe it's not possible since the docs says "This `magic` command can either take a local filename, a URL, an history range (see `%history`) or a macro as argument".

Comment: You can do it if you mount the remote directory in your local filesystem, e.g. using [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs).